# How to I Add In Degree Symbols to Temperatures in a Javascript String?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string that was returned from an API, and I want to add in degree symbols from the temperatures that are included ("Tomorrow will be a high of 89F" → "Tomorrow will be a high of 89°F"). What would the Regex look like for my variable named `forecastString`?

Answer (score 1):

This replace will work:

```
forecastString = forecastString.replace(/[0-9]{1,3}F/g, function addDegreeSymbol(x){return x.replace("F", "°F");});
forecastString = forecastString.replace(/[0-9]{1,3}C/g, function addDegreeSymbol(x){return x.replace("C", "°C");});
```

The Regex finds any numbers of 1-3 digits followed immediately by an F/C, and replaces the F/C with °F/°C

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
forecastString.replace(/\b(\d{1,3})(?=[FC]\b)/, "$1°");
```

? Are you sure about case insensitivity?

Comment: Was about to post the same, but I would add a `\b` in front of the numbers, otherwise the upper limit of 3 is useless. I think case sensitivity makes sense in this case, as the unit symbol is uppercase. On the other hand one might add a `\s*` behind the numbers to allow spaces.

Comment: The answer to "why not?" is because I'm a noob :)

Comment: @xd1936 I've updated the regex. I suggest you, if you want, the unicode symbols `℃` and `℉`.

Comment: @horcrux Man, this is why I posted here even though I thought I had a working solution. I had no idea there was a Unicode character for this! Awesome, thank you.

Comment: Ugh, please do not use the unicode character for this. `°` is part of of ascii (code `\xb0`) and pretty much guaranteed everywhere.

Comment: @naomik This string is eventually sent to Twitter. Can you think of a situation where a user is reading tweets on a device that isn't able to render `℃` and `℉`?

Comment: @xd1936 go crazy. I personally think the symbols look like garbage. And chances are, almost any font you use doesn't have a glyph defined for those code points.